# Python3(Urllib) -<bound method HTTPResponse.read of <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x03281BD0>>

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

```
import urllib.request

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://jshawl.com/python-playground/')
s = html.read
print(s)
```

This is the Error I get:

> <bound method HTTPResponse.read of <http.client.HTTPResponse object at
>   0x032B18D0>>

How do I fix this error? What mistake am I making?

Comment: Remove unnecessary image that could have just be pasted as text (with markup)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see printed is not an error - you see the `HTTPResponse` instance method string representation. To get what a method returns, you should *call it*:

```
s = html.read()
```